# Can anything be done about a bluetooth mouse moving sluggisly?

Tags: bluetooth, logitech-mouse

I have a bluetooth [Logitech V470 mouse](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/v470-cordless-laser-mouse-for-bluetooth?crid=7). It is a great mouse in every respect, but one - in comparison to my wired mouse (which is a really cheap regular [vulgaris mouse](http://www.geniusnet.com/wSite/ct?xItem=16498&ctNode=104&mp=1) (not even sure it is the model shown)) it moves very "sluggisly". It is hard to explain, but I have a feeling that when I'm moving the mouse the cursor follows with a certain time lag. Also seems less precise, but that could just be a subjective feeling.

Is there anything (special drivers? control program?) that could be done to help with that?

I'm using it via bluetooth connection in Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried new batteries? Make sure you are not using rechargeable ones. Ideally you should try to keep a reasonably clear path between the receiver and the mouse as certain objects may impair the signal - perhaps try using a different port if you can find one that is closer. Also, you may want to try changing the mouse speed settings via **Control Panel->Mouse->Pointer Options** as it is possible that it is not lag that you are experiencing but simply different speed to what you are used to.

Comment: @James - There is nothing wrong with the batteries. I didn't understand your point about a different port - it's a bluetooth mouse. The effect I was describing has nothing to do with pointer speed, but literally lags behind the physical movement of the mouse.

Comment: I mean move the bluetooth receiver, e.g. if you have a desktop PC and it is at the back then move it to a port at the front. It sounds like your issue is probably related to bad signal as I have experienced the same issue myself, and moving the mouse closer to the receiver has normally fixed it.

Comment: @Idigas: Also, I assume you are using it on a suitable surface? Even laser mice don't normally work on glass etc.

Comment: @James - Oh I'm sorry, I misunderstood. No, the machine in question is a laptop and I have reasons to believe there is nothing wrong with the bluetooth, since I'm using it for a variety of other devices as well. Yes, it is on an adequate surface (works the same way with the other machine, so I'm pretty sure it's either a mouse or a drivers/software issue).

Comment: @Idigas: Have you tried installing the SetPoint software? It could be worth a go. http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/v470-cordless-laser-mouse-for-bluetooth?section=downloads&softwareid=671&bit=32&osid=14&crid=398

Comment: @James - Have not, since it seemed to do too many (unwanted) things, but I'll give it a try if you think it could help.

Answer (score 0):

Get a magnifying glass! Look into the hole where the laser is situated. You see 2 lenses. Mine were covered with dust. I took a tissue and folded it into a point where it would fit inside the hole. I removed most of the dust that way and the problem was solved!! Mouse works fine again.
Remember when vacuuming the house, don't skip the mousehole. The rodent will be grateful and keep performing its service.